# Conditional construction with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr

I have:

```
Command *command;

if(commandType == "Start")
{
  command = new StartCommand();
}
else if (commandType == "Stop")
{
  command = new StopCommand();
}
```

Now suppose I want `command` to be a shared_ptr, how do I translate the code above to use a shared_ptr?

Comment: Substitute `Command*` with `shared_ptr<Command>`? (And preferrably `new XXXCommand()` with `make_shared<XXXCommand>()`.)

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Command> command;`, and then when assigning, do `command.reset(new StartCommand)` (or the other one)?

Comment: @birryree: Thanks I think it was the reset function I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skipping the obvious, if you want to properly initialise your variable, e.g. if it's `const`, you could do it like this

```
std::shared_ptr<Command> factoryCommand(std::string const& commandType) {
  if(commandType == "Start")
    return std::make_shared<StartCommand>();
  if(commandType == "Stop")
    return std::make_shared<StopCommand>();
  return std::shared_ptr<Command>(nullptr);
}

std::shared_ptr<Command> const command {factoryCommand(commandType)};
```

---

As indicated in the comments, you can also violate the RAII guideline of C++ and separate definition and initialisation. I would still prefer to use `std::shared_ptr<Command>::operator=` over `std::shared_ptr<Command>::reset` though, as it is more intuitive and doesn't trick you into `new`ing something you will never `delete`.

So, for the `"Start"` branch, for example, this would look like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Command> command;
//...
// I would flag this in the review process as "you're doing it wrong"
command.reset(new StartCommand());
// This is what you should do if you *have* to separate definition and initialisation:
command = std::make_shared<StartCommand>();
```

Comment: +1 Alternatively (worse, just for completion): `factoryCommand.reset( new XXXCommand() )`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Actually I was first thinking of posting this with an immediately called lambda instead of `factoryCommand`, but that wouldn't have helped to clarify the actual issue, so the function got a name.

Comment: Although my example suggested it, I wasn't only interested in the factory pattern.  I guess my question was truly how to assign to a shared_ptr.  If you add the example of using the reset function to your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: "violate the RAII guideline of C++" That doesn't break RAII. Well, it breaks what the RAII acronym is literally about, but RAII is more interested in the cleanup than the acquisition. It's still exception safe, and it's still stack-bound, so it will still be cleaned up. So what's bad about it? It's no different than creating an empty `vector` and filling it with stuff later.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Well, perhaps it's personal taste, then. But I don't see why variables that will only be written to once, near their definition, should be non-const.

Comment: Why is the assignment with `make_shared` preferred over `reset`?

Comment: @User: It kind of follows the philosophy "Destruct exactly what you create" or to rephrease: "Create only what you will later destruct". It's not wrong to use the `reset`+`new` version, but if you get into the habit of using `make_shared` in *every* case where you cannot guarantee that *you* will be the *owner* of the object and later dispatch it yourself, you will be less prone to memory leaks. Note that there is an infinitesimal period where you have a pointer, that is not bound to the `shared_ptr`, yet. That's before actually invoking `reset`.

Comment: @User: Additionally, you are not actually `reset`ting the pointer. You are initialising it. Intuitively `reset` seems to imply "throw away what you got and take ownership of this new thing here". Although functionally this also holds for the assignment operator. At the end of the day, it may be a question of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Some very simple changes will do the job:

```
shared_ptr<Command> command;

if(commandType == "Start")
{
  command = make_shared<StartCommand>();
}
else if (commandType == "Stop")
{
  command = make_shared<StopCommand>();
}
```